# Error: "Invalid column name 'ApplicationUser_Id'" when adding claims

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, claims

I was adding claims in the repository like this and it was working fine:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ExperienceMap());
}
```

But when I added the application user to the code, it throws the error shown below the next block of code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...

    //Error occurs when I add this
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers").HasKey<string>(l => l.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ExperienceMap());
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

The error is thrown in my UserClaims repo at the first AddOrUpdate:

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(IEnumerable<IdentityUserClaim> claims, Expression<Func<IdentityUserClaim, Object>> identifierExpression = null)
{
    foreach (var claim in claims)
    {
        if (identifierExpression != null)
            DataAccess.UserClaims.AddOrUpdate(identifierExpression, claim); //where the error occurs
        else
            DataAccess.UserClaims.AddOrUpdate(claim);
    }
    DataAccess.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: The default entity does not have column at all.

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
{
    public class IdentityUserClaim<TKey>
    {
        public IdentityUserClaim();
        public virtual string ClaimType { get; set; }
        public virtual string ClaimValue { get; set; }
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual TKey UserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the ApplicationUser Entity

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public bool FirstTimeLogin { get; set; }
    public bool HasConsent { get; set; }
    public DateTime ConsentDate { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationIdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationIdentityContext()
        : base("ApplicationDbContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationIdentityContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationIdentityContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that the database tables has column "ApplicationUser_Id" ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've updated my question, the database does not have the column at all and it shouldn't because it is not on the entity.

Comment: We need to see the ApplicationUser entity you have defined.  By default, EF will use Id as the PK.  If it doesn't find that, it will use <tablename>_Id as the PK name.  If neither of those fields exist on the table, it'll blow up.  You would have to specify the column name manually.

Comment: The Id column exists in the db, but not on the entity itself.

Comment: Any reason  you haven't created a property in the Entity and mapped it to the "Id" column?

Comment: When I add this to ApplicationUser `public string Id { get; set; }`, VS says that it hides the inherited member

Comment: Any solution? I am having this problem as well...

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs because `ApplicationUser` inherits from `IdentityUser` and Entity Framework can't figure out the proper ID so instead of the correct "Id" it writes "ApplicationUser_Id."

**To correct this, you can add the following line to ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder):**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey<string>(l => l.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem while i was working with asp.net core 3 so, i did this in DbContext -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{          

   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
            {
                //Each User can have many entries in the UserRole join table
                b.HasMany(e => e.Roles)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();
            });
}
```

Important is first call base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); after that assign your table relationship. That was solved my problem.

Comment: With that, UserId 1 will be mapped to RoleId 1 and so on

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I did some relation changes involving ApplicationUser in the DbContext on the OnModelCreating method and I didn't update my migration.