# How can I properly configure ASP.NET Identity so that I can maintain two db contexts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, .net-4.8

I have an interesting situation with the configuration of ASP.NET Identity entities. No matter what I add to the configuration classes for my entities, I am getting an error saying "Invalid column name ApplicationUser_Id."

Here are some details about my architecture:

- I configured my ASP.NET Identity entities so that the data type of their primary keys is `int` (with the exception of AspNetUserLogins and AspNetUserRoles, which both use composite primary keys).
- I attempted to create an architecture where my non-Identity context (let's call it my domain context) inherits from my Identity context, which inherits from DbContext, of course. I did this so that my domain context could access the entities in my Identity context, but not the other way around. (Correct me if this is a bad idea.)
- My Identity entities do not add any additional properties to what ASP.NET Identity already has put in (nor do they remove any). The only customization here is that the primary keys are integers, as previously stated.

My Identity context:

```
 public class IdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, AppRole, int, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim>
    {
        public IdentityDbContext()
            : base("connectionString")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //Configuration for ASP.NET Identity entities
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AppUserLoginConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AppUserRoleConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AppRoleConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AppUserClaimConfiguration());
        }
    }
```

My domain context:

```
public class DbContext : IdentityDbContext, IDbContext
    {
        public DbSet<EventLog> EventLogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Listing> Listings { get; set; }

        public DbContext()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EventLogConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SiteConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ListingConfiguration());

            //non-fluent configuration
            //modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(k => k.Id).ToTable("AspNetUsers", "dbo");
            //modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserLogin>().HasKey(k => k.Id).ToTable("AspNetUserLogins", "dbo");
            //modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserRole>().HasKey(k => k.Id).ToTable("AspNetUserRoles", "dbo");
            //modelBuilder.Entity<AppRole>().HasKey(k => k.Id).ToTable("AspNetRoles", "dbo");
            //modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserClaim>().HasKey(k => k.Id).ToTable("AspNetUserClaims", "dbo");
        }

        public static DbContext Create()
        {
            return new DbContext();
        }

    }
}
```

Identity entity configurations:

```
public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("AspNetUsers", "dbo");
            HasKey(k => k.Id);
        }
    }

 public class AppRoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AppRole>
    {
        public AppRoleConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("AspNetRoles", "dbo");
            HasKey(k => k.Id);
        }
    }

public class AppUserClaimConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AppUserClaim>
    {
        public AppUserClaimConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("AspNetUserClaims", "dbo");
            HasKey(k => k.Id);
        }
    }

 public class AppUserLoginConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AppUserLogin>
    {
        public AppUserLoginConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("AspNetUserLogins", "dbo");
            HasKey(k => new { k.LoginProvider, k.ProviderKey, k.UserId });
        }
    }

public class AppUserRoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AppUserRole>
    {
        public AppUserRoleConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("AspNetUserRole", "dbo");
            HasKey(k => new { k.RoleId, k.UserId });            
        }
    }
```

Domain entity configurations:

```
public class EventLogConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<EventLog>
    {
        public EventLogConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("EventLog", "Core");
            HasKey(k => k.Id);
        }
    }

public class ListingConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Listing>
    {
        public ListingConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Listings", "Catalog");
            HasKey(k => k.Id);
        }
    }

public class SiteConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Site>
    {
        public SiteConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(k => k.Id);
            ToTable("Sites", "Site");
        }
    }
```

The entity configurations for my domain entities work just fine, but the configurations for my Identity entities do not seem to be working. As you can see above, I am not adding a column called "ApplicationUser_Id" in any of the Identity entities or their configurations. I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096084/error-invalid-column-name-applicationuser-id-when-adding-claims), but, even after trying what the proposed answer was, I was unsuccessful in fixing this error.

Here is the line of code my application breaks on in the Account Controller:

```
.
.
.
var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
.
.
.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. If I can add any more information, please let me know. I've been stuck on this issue for a couple nights now, so I'm eager to get it fixed. Thanks!

Edit: Summarizing the question

My problem is that ASP.NET Identity seems to be looking for a database column called "ApplicationUser_Id" in the ApplicationUser table.  Why is Identity looking for this database column when, as you can see in my configuration classes above, that column does not exist. I'm even using the `HasKey` method where I'm setting the key to the proper column (Id). Am I missing something in either of my context classes, or am I missing something in my configuration classes?

The Identity tables were put in the dbo schema of my database by default, so I left them there. Schema name is the second parameter of the `ToTable` method above in my configuration classes.

Comment: I had trouble reading through this question to figure out what it is you need. What are your requirements? Have you tried doing custom identity database?

Comment: @theMayer Thanks for the reply. I need to figure out why Identity is looking for a database column called "ApplicationUser_Id." I didn't configure any of my entities to have a column by that name.

Comment: There are built in defaults and one of them is the entire database schema. You can use your own custom schema but configuring this is better left to an article, which there are some good ones out there if you search.